# Initialize a subclass of UIViewController with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I'm trying to understand how initialization works in Swift with a subclass of a UIViewController. I thought the basic format was this, but it is throwing errors...

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)   {
    //other code
    super.init(nibName: String?, bundle: NSBundle?)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You're passing the types, not the variables. You have to pass the variables instead.

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)  {
    // Initialize variables.

    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

Comment: You should always initialize your variables before calling super.

Answer (score 4):

Variables should now be initialized before the call to super.init

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!)  {

    // Initialize variables.

    super.init() // as required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize with/without parameters.

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

// Default Initializer
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}

// Initialize with value
init(_ sender: Any?) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```